# Play specific video from loop OnClick in Vue.JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Let's assume that this 2 video is the output from a for loop with the the method of play() and with an index parameter. How can i play the specific video, because when i trigger the play method it also play the second video.

**Component's HTML**

```
<div class="relative">
  <video id="videoElement" class="sm:hidden block md:h-auto md:w-auto w-full h-auto object-cover object-center mx-auto focus:outline-none" controls="false" v-play="playing">
    <source src="~/assets/video/video1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
  <img @click="play('1')" src="~/assets/img/play-button.svg" class="sm:hidden h-12 w-12 absolute m-auto inset-0 z-50 top-0">
 </div>
<div class="relative">
  <video id="videoElement" class="sm:hidden block md:h-auto md:w-auto w-full h-auto object-cover object-center mx-auto focus:outline-none" controls="false" v-play="playing">
    <source src="~/assets/video/video2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
  <img @click="play('2')" src="~/assets/img/play-button.svg" class="sm:hidden h-12 w-12 absolute m-auto inset-0 z-50 top-0">
 </div>
```

**Component's JavaScript**

```
export default { 
  data(){
  return {
    playing: false
  }
 },
 computed: {
    paused() {
      return !this.playing;
    }
  },
  directives: {
    play: {
      bind(el, binding, vnode) {
        el.addEventListener('playing', () => {
          vnode.context[binding.expression] = !el.paused;
        });
        el.addEventListener('pause', () => {
          vnode.context[binding.expression] = !el.paused;
        });
        vnode.context[binding.expression] = !el.paused;
      },
      update(el, binding) {
        if (el.paused) {
          if (binding.value) {
            el.play();
          }
        } else if (!binding.value) {
          el.pause();
        }
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    play(index) {
    this.playing = !this.playing;      
    },  
    pause() {
      this.playing = false;
    }
  }
 }
</script>
```

Comment: My working fiddle version: https://jsfiddle.net/jfpwtkm0/1/ , Feel free share your thoughts. I used `v-for` since your HTML on video with duplicate `id` was weird.

Answer (score 0):

Converting comment to answer for future reference

My working fiddle version: https://jsfiddle.net/jfpwtkm0/1 
Feel free share your thoughts:

- I used `v-for` since your HTML on video with duplicate id was weird as it would be practical in actual video datafetching case instead of manual-templating each video
- Custom directive was not mapped to each Object's `playing` state, so i've changed that format to be assigned to video with their `id` respectively
- updated `toggle(id)` method, since you're planning to change the `playState`, so i include `id` so the `playState` of videoObject toggled according the index.
- Same `id` value in multiple elements is not practical. I assigned the id of the videoArray to be unique.

If this answer solved your question, green tick will help alot, cheers :)